# ATS warning but Temporary exception active?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security, network-security

I have a weird issue, 
I keep getting `App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP  (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`, but I have enabled an exception , as well as opening the whole app for ATS, but my preference is ignored by Xcode even though my other keys are in use.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, can someone tell me if anything strikes them as hugely wrong in my keys?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AUTH_SERVER_URL</key>
    <string>https://$(Auth_Server_Url)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>MKDirectionsRequest</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.apple.maps.directionsrequest</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fr.cityzenmobility.drivers</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>MKDirectionsModeCar</string>
        <string>MKDirectionsModeStreetCar</string>
        <string>MKDirectionsModeTaxi</string>
    </array>
```

Here's the part that should work:

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>www.mysite.fr</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Then the end of the *Info.plist* file:

```
    <key>SERVERURL</key>
    <string>http://${Server_Url}</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Welcome</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**EDIT**

I've built a brand new project, with the exact same Info.plist. It works, henceforth the problem is not with the network part itself.

Comment: Looks like the value for your `NSThirdPartyException...` key is an empty string instead of `true`

Comment: @dan Well spotted, but sadly it does not fix the issue. I think I'm going to make a brand new project just for testing this out...

Comment: Just discovered this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1887/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40015177 which helps with this type of issue, hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason, after a complete reboot of the Mac, a git clone of the project, a full clean of the project and build files, as well as the iPhone, the code started behaving as expected.

I assume some cached file was misbehaving...